# How to define Variables in a Function by Input?

Tags: python, function, input

I would be really happy if someone could help me with this promblem, cuz I am kinda stuck here. I am trying to 'trigger' the function, by calling it by name and afterwards adding the variables, by writing numbers, which are split by a space between.

```
#I tried:
#(Input: Test1 4 5)
Input = input().split()

def Test1(X,Y = 3):
     print(X,Y)

dic = {'Test1':Test1}
dic[Input[0]](Input[1:len(Input)])
#But it wil give me: ['4', '5'] 3 instead of just 4 5
```

I want to define X and Y, not just X what I just did.

I am using py3.0

I am very thankful for every Suggestion

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think it would "separate the list in two"? `Input[1:len(Input)]` is a single argument.

Comment: ok, but then how to get two Arguments from that. That I define X and Y and not just X?

Comment: So you are basically trying call the Test1 method by parsing the method name and arguments from a string separated by spaces?

Comment: `Input` is a list of strings, the input string split on spaces. Nothing in your code converts those strings to numbers.

Comment: Add a * `dic[Input[0]](*Input[1:len(Input)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "spread"/apply a list of arguments to a function using `*`:

```
dic[Input[0]](*Input[1:len(Input)])
```

Note the `*`. `Input[1:len(Input)]` on its own passes the input list as `x`. `*` spreads the list out so it's treated as multiple arguments. Think of it as flattening the list of data into the argument list.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn the list into string by doing `join` like this:

```
Input = input().split()

def Test1(X,Y = 3):
     print(X,Y)

dic = {'Test1':Test1} dic[Input[0]](' '.join(Input[1:len(Input)]))
```

If you're confused why it's still printing 3 afterwards, well the function Test1 accepts two variables but you are passing only one variable to it, so it prints the other one (Y) which you set a default value for, if you would like to do something with Y I'm afraid you'll need to explain further what you had in mind.

Comment: Note the output. They only want `4 5`.